# Which one is better to access the MySQL in online from Android application? Either RESTful web service or Async Task?

Tags: php, android, mysql, rest, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android application where my application uses MySQL as database via PHP. Now I am developing an application with RESTful web service. I want to know which one is better for accessing the database? Either RESTful web service or Async Task?

Please explain with an example.

Comment: Both, I think. Use async task to do http request to a REST API or am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: @frz3993 I am using only RESTful web service. What is the different between both?

Comment: I would recommend using Retrofit to consume the service, it's great: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: A REST API is the API to access the service. The web service will provide access to the server's resources. You use asynctask so you don't block your activity's main thread. In you asynctask, make a request to the web service using whatever library you are comfortable with. Example `httpurlconnection`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues and remove the thanks, which is not required.  You show your thanks by voting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go straight REST. It's much easier for error handling and imo a bit easier.